# I can't create any type of file

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.2

[image]

[image]

I clicked the ok button and nothing happened.

I tried to restart or uninstall the installation, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try Android studio older one

Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: I used this version before, can't create

Comment: I think this is not Android studio issue brother